# Cannot ssh to WSL from windows PC

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to ssh to WSL on my windows PC.
The port forwarding rule has been set up properly with netsh.

```
ADDRESS         PORT        ADDRESS         PORT      
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
0.0.0.0         3333        172.19.56.231   22
```

The address to be connected is obtained through `wsl -d "Ubuntu-22.04" hostname -I`

I can ssh to WSL through `ssh shflte@172.19.56.231`. But I cannot ssh to WSL through `ssh shflte@192.168.100.156 -p 3333`(192.168.100.156 is my PC's address).  So I guess the problem did not come from the WSL.

ssh message:

```
ssh shflte@192.168.100.156 -p 3333 -v
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\SH/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.100.156 [192.168.100.156] port 3333.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.100.156 port 3333: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.156 port 3333: Connection refused
```

Can anyone tell me why did I get `Connection refused`?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly related to a firewall problem. To verify that the firewall is allowing incoming connections on port 3333, you can do the following command in PowerShell:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all dir=in | findstr "3333"
```

In the case where the firewall is actually the problem, you can allow incoming connections on port 3333:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH_WSL" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3333
```